# i have to find which charecter deleted from string on keypress of keydown.backspace event

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-forms

**HTML:**

```
<input mdInput #sampleInput
  (keyup.enter) = "autoAdd(sampleInput)"
  [mdAutocomplete] = "AutocompleteParameter"
  [(ngModel)] = "AutoParameterVal"
placeholder = "Autoparameters..."
  (keyup.enter) = "autoKeyEnter($event.target.value)"
    (keydown.backspace) = "onBackspaceKeydown($event)"
 />
```

**TS:**

```
   onBackspaceKeydown(event) { 
    console.log('event',event)
   }
```

> i have to detect which charecter is deleted from string on press of backspace by using keydown.backspace event .plz help me to sort out this.

Comment: If I hold down either Backspace or Delete, then multiple characters could be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selectionStart to Detect the position of the Caret

```
 AutoParameterVal='Sample';
 onBackspaceKeydown($event,ref){
     console.log(ref.selectionStart);
     this.AutoParameterVal[ref.selectionStart-1]
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1oedu4

Comment: @Chellappan.thnx a lot.